# Who owns "Heartsbane" at the end of Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

After the end of *Game of Thrones*, who owns "Heartsbane"?

Heartsbane was given to Jorah by Samwell Tarly because Ser Jorah's father cared for Tarly during his tenure as Lord Commander of the Night's Watch. As Ser Jorah died protecting his queen, who owns Heartsbane now?

Sam doesn't need it as he became a maester.

Comment: We don't know, Sam can give it to any survivor I guess but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Why down votes?

Comment: @MightyBeard007 because no one knows. There is no answer given in the show.

Comment: We don't know is an acceptable answer here if reasoned correctly

Comment: @Gabriel just because it's not explained in the show, doesn't stop it being a good question. One might actually argue that the best questions are ones such as this

Comment: @Bee I kind of feel like this isn't a good question though. We can only speculate about where the sword went but at the end of the day what does it matter? White walkers were destroyed so having a Valyrian steel sword doesn't really matter aside from the family history. It probably went to whatever house was decided to take over the Tarly's holdings. And figuring that out is all speculation best left to writers of fan fiction.

Comment: IMO the question has weight since throughout the series Heartsbane played a significant role in Sam's story as well as his relationship with other characters, however, since there's literally no evidence to support any kind of speculation as to who owns it now, in the end, the question falls on a moot point. +1 but also VTC.

Comment: @Charles whats VTC?

Comment: @MightyBeard007 Vote To Close. Reasoning: opinion-based. *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*

Comment: @Gabriel but there will be a definitive answer to this. It's not an opinion it's just very speculative right now. It's likely that it will either be explained when the next books are published or when someone asks one of the show producers in an interview

Comment: @Bee I wouldn't give any weight to what any of the show producers say on this subject. I would give weight if the book said what happens to the sword but I still feel like this question should be VTC cause it is pure speculation at this point. Whenever the last two books come out this question I feel would be valid but on the Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange. But again we don't know if GRRM will spend time explaining any of the aftermath of where these Valyrian steel swords end up.

Answer (score 1):

In the HBO cannon the Valyrian steel swords ended up not mattering so it is not canonically addressed. We can only presume that Heartsbane suffered a similar fate to Widows Wail, buried under some rubble and forgotten. Who finds them after is unknown. Could be a random peasant.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to cut and paste, but honestly I feel GOT wiki gives a good (and possibly the only) answer. Here it is.

> Samwell, feeling guilty, tells Daenerys and Jorah Mormont that he "borrowed" Heartsbane. Samwell later gives his family's ancestral sword to Jorah (due to its Valyrian properties allowing it to kill White Walkers), who promises to wield it for the Battle of Winterfell to honor of his late father, Jeor Mormont, who Sam also saw as father figure. Towards the end of the Great Battle, Jorah fends off many wights in order to protect Daenerys, getting stabbed multiple times in the process and eventually succumbing to his wounds. The current owner of the Valyrian blade is unknown.

So honestly anyone or no one could have it.